# c++ map doesn't return end() even though it should

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, dictionary, segmentation-fault

In my code I have a map (`tBoxes`) with `vector<int>` begin the key and `set< pair<int,int> >` being the value.

For some reason, the program crash with segmentation fault when I try to access a specific element of the map which is empty. If I run the program through valgrind all is well (that is how I know the element is empty). Also, valgrind doesn't state any memory leak. The loop I'm using is a naive one:

```
map<vector<int>,set<int, int> > tBoxes;


/*populate boxes*/

vector<int> t(3,0);
set<pair<int, int> >::iterator it;

for(int i = mini; i <= maxi; i++){
  t[0] = i;
  for (int j = minj; j <= maxj; j++){
    t[1] = j;
    for (int k = mink; k <= maxk; k++){
      t[2] = k;
      it = tBoxes[t].begin();
      while (it != tBoxes[t].end()){
        it++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:

The code is not a direct copy-pate from my file since I use weird variable names.
I suspect this is an issue with memory allocation of the map but I don't know how to fix this. Also, the value is a `set` and not a `vector`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your declaration for `it` isn't an actual copy-paste of your code, as it's completely the wrong type. Also, you've omitted your declaration for `tBoxes`, how you fill it and a bunch of other things. It would help to have a relatively complete code snippet. I have my doubts that the problem is in the code you've posted.

Comment: @pmjordan you're much more polite then I was going to be.

Comment: Code _still_ doesn't compile.   `tBoxes[t].begin()` returns a `std::map<vector<int>,set<int, int> >::iterator`, not a `set<pair<int, int> >::iterator`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: ``it`` is an iterator now

Comment: A map with a vector as a key is, while possible, still a really, really bad idea.

Comment: @Yotam: Yes, but it's the _wrong kind_ of iterator, and still doesn't compile.  Since this is obviously not your real code, I'm going to go on a limb, and say this code doesn't have your real bug either, and that we'll be unable to help still.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't understand why would ``tBoxes[t]`` return ``vector`` if ``tBoxes`` values are ``set`` now. Also, I am sure the bug is not in this scheme since it worked at least twice in this run before crushing. I actually want to know why would using [t] cause segmentation fault.

Comment: @KerrekSB: How would you do it then? I tried to used a 3d vector which was headache to maintain and gain similar response...

Comment: @Yotam: I misread, `tBoxes[t]` will indeed return that type of iterator, as shown [here](http://codepad.org/8Eszlf5T).  However, like the link shows, this code has no errors.  Works fine.  We can't help you without a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Yotam: How would I do *what*? I don't even know what problem you're trying to solve!

Comment: @KerrekSB He appears to be mapping 3d coordinates to `sets` of stuff.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That would call for a tuple key, not a vector key.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int k = mink; k <= maxj; k++){ // should'n it be maxk?
```

The old "copy-and-paste the for" error :D

EDIT: Op changed the code and corrected what i pointed out, so this answer is no longer valid...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
complete rewrite to insert an int into a set of ints which is then inserted into a map of vectors of ints to sets of ints.  (Sic.)  Then retrieving the original int.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv )
{
    map< vector<int>, set<int> > tBoxes;

    vector<int> vecInsert( 3, 0 );
    set<int> setInsert;
    setInsert.insert( 666 );

    tBoxes.insert( std::make_pair( vecInsert, setInsert ) );

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    vector<int> vecLookup( 3, 0 ); //identical to vecInsert
    set<int> setLookup =  tBoxes[vecLookup]; //the set mapped by the 'key' vector above
    set<int>::iterator iter = setLookup.begin(); //the first element in the set

    if( iter != setLookup.end() )
    {
        int i = *iter;
        if( i == 666 )
        {
            //eureka!!
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: No. I also have a part that populate the boxes. My edit state what I did that fix this.